# Predicting when and where 2 points with non-constant velocity will collide

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, physics, collision-detection

I am trying to estimate when and where 2 objects will collide with non-constant velocites which also have thrust and friction considerations. This for a physics simulation I am working on where I have to collide a missile with another object, given the information that:
$$
\vec{V_n} = \vec{V_{n-1}}f+ s/m
$$
$$  
P_n = P_{n-1} + \vec{V_n}
$$
$$
\vec{U_n} = \vec{U_{n-1}}\cdot g
$$
$$
Q_n = Q_{n-1} + \vec{U_n}
$$
$$
D_n = ||Q_n - P_n||
$$

Solve $D_n = 0$ for $n$

Where:

- $P$ and $Q$ are coordinates for the positions of the two objects
- $\vec{V}$ and $\vec{U}$ are the velocities of the objects
- all vectors are 2-dimensional ($<x,y>$)
- $D_n$ is the distance between $P$ and $Q$ at time n
- $s$ is a thrust value to add to $V$
- $m$ is an object mass
- $f$ and $g$ are friction coefficients
- 0 < $f$ < 1
- 0 < $g$ < 1
- $P_0$, $Q_0$, $\vec{V_0}$, and $\vec{U_0}$ are known
- $s$, $m$, and $f$, $g$ are all supplied constants
- I.e. the only unknown is $n$

Now I have figured out the position functions for $P_n$ and $Q_n$ by simply solving the recurrence relations:
$$Q_n = Q_0 + \frac{g(g^n - 1)}{g - 1}U_0$$
$$P_n = P_0 + \frac{f(f^n - 1)}{f - 1}V_0 + \frac{\lambda f(f^n - 1)}{(f - 1)^2} - \frac{\lambda n}{f - 1}$$
$$\lambda = \frac{s}{m}$$

And I know that a collision will occur when $P_n - Q_n = 0 = D_n$. My problem is that this expression involves 3 unknowns ($f^n$, $g^n$ and $n$) and I would preferably like to not tackle $D_n = 0$ by trial and error. I know that I can approach this problem by an [egg drop](http://datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html) approach  which will reduce the amount of trial and error to at most $log_2(n)$ tries. The thing is that I have been told that this problem can be solved in constant time so I think thre must be a better way to tackle this problem.

I just need to be pushed on the right track (ie technique concept) about how this would be solved in a more direct sense.

Comment: Seems to me your first equation can't work unless $s$ is a vector.

Comment: Ah sorry s is a vector, s represents thrust.

Comment: In your final solution for $P_{n}$, a term $\lambda$ occurs and I don't know what it is, and it seems to me that $s$ should occur in the final solution but it doesn't.

If the parameters of your problem which are vector quantities are arbitrary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $n>1$, then it seems to me there is no guarantee that a collision will occur for any positive integer $n$. Kind of weird to be making it a function of a discrete variable $n$, anyway.

Comment: Sorry $\lambda = \frac{s}{m}$ I have edited the post to reflect this. I also agree that it is weird yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**3D case**

$Q_n$ appears to belong to the line $(Q_0, \vec{U}_0)$ for all $n$. $P_n$ belongs to the plane $(P_0, \vec{V}_0, \vec{s})$ (is $s$ a constant vector ?). *If* they collide, this is in the intersection (if it exists, and unless the line belongs to the plane). Your formulae then give you $n$ to reach this point for each object, if they are equal then there is collision. You have to treat the case when the line is in the plane separately (2D case).

**2D case**

Find $n$ such that $P_n \in (Q_0, \vec U_0)$. Then find $m$ such that $Q_m=P_n$. If $m=n$ then there is collision.

Comment: Yes $s$ is a given constant vector, a thrust added to $V_n$

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that I am only working in a 2d space so I just be looking for an intersection of 2 lines in that case right?